# Populate int[ ] array from console on 1 line with Lambda (java)

Tags: java, arrays, lambda, java-8

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))) {
     Object[] test = Arrays.stream(br.readLine().split(" ")).map(string -> Integer.parseInt(string)).toArray();
     System.out.println(Arrays.toString(test));
} catch (IOException E) {

}
```

So this code works but it returns an array of type `Object[]`
However, what I want is to make it return an array of type `int[]`.

does anyone have an idea of how I can accomplish that?

Comment: so you want to return an array of `int` rather than an array of `Object`?

Comment: yes i want it to return an int[] not an Object[]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

to retrieve an array of `int` type rather than `Object`, you can use the [`mapToInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapToInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-) method.

```
int[] test = Arrays.stream(br.readLine().split(" "))
                   .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
```

note that you can simplify your code by using a [method reference](https://www.codementor.io/eh3rrera/using-java-8-method-reference-du10866vx) within the argument of the [`mapToInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapToInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-) method.

reading:

- [MKyong Java 8 Tutorials](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/java-8-tutorials/) (my favorite)
- [tutorialspoint Java 8 Tutorials](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java8/)
- [ConcretePage Java 8 tutorials](http://www.concretepage.com/java/jdk-8/)

Comment: ok to will makr with best when it lets me. Didint knew it was a simple as that. Btw can you give a link for a good tutorial on Lambda, cause there arent a lot and the ones in oracle are ...

Comment: sure, give me a minute.

Comment: hey, 1 quick question popped, so with `collect(Collectors.toList()`' we return a List<T> , and respectively with `Collectors.toSet()` and `Collectors.toMap()` a map<k,v> and a set<k>, but for ArrayList i cant find anything? ..toArray() doesn't work as well

Comment: @ВсеЕдно you can convert a stream into an `ArrayList` with `.collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));` but because `ArrayList` is of type `List` you can simply use `.collect(Collectors.toList());` which will convert the stream into a List. However, is there any reason you don't want to use `.collect(Collectors.toList());`? more info about [**How to get ArrayList from Stream in Java 8**](http://www.java67.com/2016/03/how-to-get-arraylist-from-stream-in-java8-example.html).

Comment: if you want to retrieve a `List<T>` instead of an array then use this: `List<Integer> test = Arrays.stream(br.readLine().split(" "))                         .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: `ArrayList<Integer> arrList = Arrays.stream(br.readLine().split(" "))
                .mapToInt(string -> Integer.parseInt(string))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());` and        `ArrayList<Integer> arrList = Arrays.stream(br.readLine().split(" "))
                .map(string -> Integer.parseInt(string))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());` throw errors i cant do it with `.toList()`

Comment: I'd suggest you use the approach of my last comment but if you really do want an `ArrayList` then use this: `ArrayList<Integer> test = Arrays.stream(br.readLine().split(" "))                         .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).boxed().collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));`

Comment: @Aominè No need to transform to `int` and then to `Integer`. Simply use: `ArrayList<Integer> ints = Stream.of(br.readLine().split(" ")).map(Integer::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));`

Comment: @Flown true , that's definitely a more concise solution! I really Appreciate the suggestion and will keep that in mind next time.